# Print real-time terminal response to tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter, stdout

Hi im currently working on a project which involves selenium and basically what i want my program to do is input the terminal responses i.e my print statements. As what i have done is for each page which loads i print out the name of the page for example "forum homepage" or "forum FAQ" to show me that my script is working correctly and i also print out timing for each  response.

So i would like these printed statements to be input into a Tkinter Text/Textbox, i know this involves stdout but i would like this to run in real time from when my selenium script starts and from when my script ends.

If you guys have got any solutions that would help me out, that would be great thanks.

Comment: From what I can understand you want to send a response_string to a tk.Text instance? Do you have any code to show what you are attempting?

Comment: To be honest there is a whole lot of code with a bunch of different functions, so in my response i feel like this is the best way for me to explain what i am attempting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an output that you need to show up in the tkinter window, use the insert() method of your an instance of tk.Text.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

# Your output
output = ['something', 'other thing', 1, 2, 3, 4]

root = tk.Tk()

# Create a tk.Text instance
myText = tk.Text()
myText.pack()

# Use the insert function to push whatever the output it to the screen
for thing in output:
    myText.insert(tk.END, f'{thing}\n')

root.mainloop()
```

This site is an excellent resource for tkinter documentation and examples: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-text-widget/